# Commiting a google web app project to github

Tags: google-app-engine, version-control, github

I have a google web application project that I want to host on github. I'm familiar with the basics of github. I have committed simple java projects. But how do I commit a google web project so that a user can just import the project from github and its created.

Do I just commit all of the source code. Then anyone who wants to import the project just creates a new project and re-imports the code from github into his/her newly created project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should commit all the source code project folder like:

```
YourProjectFolder/
    app.yaml
    application.py
    lib/
    foo/
```

One potential user will:

1. Clone the source folder from github.
2. Select *Add existing*, from the GAE Sdk dashboard,  specifying the cloned source folder.